# How do I use a new line character in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to cheat in a HTML5 game and its localStorage attributes have new lines in them, though when I do something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('gamesave', '"money":"5000"
"gold":"1000"')
```

The localStorage doesn't even save.

If I try to set a localStorage attribute with a new line in it, it will not set.
How do I include a new line in a localStorage attribute and have it save properly?

Comment: have you tried `\n`?

Comment: Im assuming `\n` creates a new line, is that what it does?

Comment: I would think so but I would have thought the developers would have saved that data in json format rather than new line and colon delimited strings

Comment: Which game?  Might help to see how they're keeping the local storage.

Comment: It's called "Idle Breakout"

Comment: What browser are you testing in, and what protocol is the page using ( i.e. file:// or http://  or https:// ). It makes a difference.

Comment: google chrome, its on an https website

Comment: `\n` is a new line escape character. When javascript encounters a `\n` it sees a line break. It doesn't even know it shows `\n` That said, like Saebs answer says, you should be serializing actual javascript because it is more sane, typo-proof, and forms a good habit for the future.

Comment: `\n` works, sarvon's answer works, and Saeb's answer works. Thanks for the feedback everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can u try es6 string literal like. it will work

```
localStorage.setItem('gamesave', `"money":"5000"
"gold":"1000"`)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save and get as an object.

> SetItem : `localStorage.setItem('gamesave', JSON.stringify({ money:5000, gold:1000 }))`
>
> GetItem : `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gamesave'))`